# Blender bone animation with extruded vertex not moving as expected

Tags: blender, skeletal-animation, bones

I'm really new to blender. I've managed to make a model body and bone structure. 
I've two problems:

1. But when I try to rotate the arm bone, my entire body moves. Why is this happening? I was following a guide and did `ctrl+P` and `armature deform -> with automatic weights` to link the bones to the mesh. What am I doing wrong here?
2. There appears to be some extruded vertex left in the joins of knee and shoulder. How do I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind we have a [dedicated Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) for asking questions about how to use Blender effectively. You may also want to add to your question some information about where your arm was when you assigned your skinning weights.

Comment: @DMGregory Okay, I'll keep that in mind. The arms are bones were in the exact same position as in the image. All I did was switch to pose mode and rotate the arm bone on the right. But doing so is moving my entire body mesh.